# Conditional conformance array protocol not recognising

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a protocol `CustomObject`, and I added extention for `String` to conform to `CustomObject`. I also added conditional conformance to `Array`(if `Element` confroms to `CustomObject`) and `Dictionary`(if key and value conforms to `CustomObject`). But when I try to assign an array that contains String and `CustomObject` to `CustomObject` variable(or pass as an argument, the compiler complaints as `Value of type '[CustomObject]' does not conform to specified type 'CustomObject'`

With conditional conformance of array, it the element is `CustomObject`, the array should also be `CustomObject`.

What is missing in this?

Code tried:

```swift
protocol CustomObject {
    var value: String { get }
}

extension String: CustomObject {
    var value: String {
        return self
    }
}

extension Array: CustomObject where Element: CustomObject {
    var value: String {
        return "{\n\(self.map{$0.value}.joined(separator: "\n"))\n}"
    }
}

extension Dictionary: CustomObject where Key: CustomObject, Value: CustomObject {
    var value: String {
        return self.map {
            return "\($0.value){\n\($1.value)\n}"
            }
            .joined(separator: "\n")
    }
}


var params = [
    "v1",
    "v2",
]
let dict1 = ["key1": params]
let dict2: CustomObject = ["key2": dict1]
let array1: CustomObject = ["key3", dict2.value]// Error here `Value of type '[CustomObject]' does not conform to specified type 'CustomObject'`


func doSomething(_ object: CustomObject) {
    //...
    print("value -- " + object.value)
}

let array2 = ["key3", dict2]
doSomething(array2)// Here also `Value of type '[CustomObject]' does not conform to specified type 'CustomObject'`
```

**UPDATE**:

If I change array extension to `extension Array: CustomObject where Element == CustomObject` This error goes away and another error comes in.

```
let dict2: CustomObject = ["key2": dict1]//Contextual type 'CustomObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal
```

Comment: The problem  is that `dict2` has the type `CustomObject` and that does not *conform* to `CustomObject`. As a consequence, `array2` does not (conditionally) conform to it either.

Comment: Okay.. as per my edit, first error goes away. Is it possible to conform a dictionary to `CustomObject`?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, using a “type eraser” `struct AnyCustomObject: CustomObject { ... }` as described in linked-to Q&A is currently the only solution. Then `let array2 = [AnyCustomObject("key3"), AnyCustomObject(dict2)] ; doSomething(array2)` should work.